# How can I make something similar to Navigation pane in Outlook?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a menu list in leftmenu.jsp file. In my page.jsp, I have a vertical button(just like Navigation Pane in outlook). When I click on the button, I want to display the menu list in leftmenu.jsp file. How can I do that?

page.jsp

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="pageNav"  style="z-index:9999; position:relative;height:180px;">
   <button id="showmenu" type="button">Hide menu</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

leftmenu.jsp

```
<div class="sidebarmenu" style="position: absolute;">
        Menu List
</div>
```

Comment: how does a navigation pane look in outlook?

Comment: "navigation pane" is displayed vertically. When clicked on it, a small menu is displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Google for jQuery menu slider, or menu toggler or jQuery Outlook like menu behaviour... 
Or you could write something yourself using jQuery.

jQuery:

```
$('#menu-wrapper').hide();

$('#btn-toggle-menu').on('click', function(e) {
    var menu = $('#menu-wrapper');
    if(menu.is(':hidden')) {
        menu.show();
    } else {
        menu.hide();
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu">M</div>
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
        <li>link item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This a very basic one and should be editted to match your needs.
A working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/) -> Click the 'M'

You could check UI's like Bootstrap or Flat UI if they have anything you like...

Goodluck!